# PhotosPicker won't appear when it embedded in popover

Tags: swift, swiftui

On visionOS 1.0 and Xcode 15.2

When I embedded a `PhotosPickerView()` in popover,
it won't work:

```
struct PhotoPickerTest: View {
    @State private var selectedPhotoItem: PhotosPickerItem?
    @State private var isTaped: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("", systemImage: "plus") {
            isTaped = true
        }
        .popover(isPresented: $isTaped) {
            PhotoPickerView()
        }
    }
    
    func PhotoPickerView() -> some View {
        PhotosPicker(selection: $selectedPhotoItem) {
            Image(systemName: "photo")
        }
    }
}
```

but if I just replace `popover` with `sheet`,

it works fine:

```
struct PhotoPickerTest: View {
    @State private var selectedPhotoItem: PhotosPickerItem?
    @State private var isTaped: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("", systemImage: "plus") {
            isTaped = true
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isTaped) {
            PhotoPickerView()
        }
    }
    
    func PhotoPickerView() -> some View {
        PhotosPicker(selection: $selectedPhotoItem) {
            Image(systemName: "photo")
        }
    }
}
```

Is it a bug, or just I did something wrong?

Comment: Which iOS and XCode version you're using? I've tried your code, and it works fine, both present PhotosPicker.

Comment: Could not replicate your issue either, the `.popover` works well for me in my tests. On MacOS 14.3, using Xcode 15.2, tested on real ios 17 devices (not Previews) and macCatalyst. It could be different on older systems.

Comment: It works fine using XCode 15.2 and iOS 17.2. Which one are you using? I've tested both versions and they work as expected. I've also tested it on iOS 16.4 and the only difference is that you don't see the selected checkmark on photos.

Comment: Sorry for forgotten to mention the platform and version. I test it on visionOS 1.0 and Xcode 15.2.